# post and put method doesn't work for me "error": "Unsupported Media Type"

Tags: json, hibernate, spring-mvc, many-to-one, rest

i have this error message when i try post and put method on patients but get  method work for me.

"error": "Unsupported Media Type",
"message": "Content type 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' not supported",

i guess the problem with @JsonBackReference. when i delete @JsonBackReference i have this error message when i try get method : There was an error parsing JSON data

Unexpected end of JSON input

code  here

class patients

```
@Entity
public class Patient {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Integer id_pat;

  private Integer cin_pat;
  private String fname_pat;
  private String lname_pat;
  private String sexe_pat;

  @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
  private Date date_naissance_pat;

  private String ville_pat;
  private String poid_pat;
  private String mail_pat;
  private Integer num_tel_pat;
  private String adress_pat;
  private String remarque_pat;
  private String malade_pat;
  private String medicament_pat;

  @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
  private Date der_soin_pat;

  private String mot_de_passe_pat;

  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="patient", orphanRemoval = true)
  private List<Rdv> Rdvs;

  public Patient(){
  }

  public Patient(Integer id_pat, Integer cin_pat, String fname_pat, String lname_pat, String sexe_pat, Date date_naissance_pat, String ville_pat, String poid_pat, String mail_pat, Integer num_tel_pat, String adress_pat, String remarque_pat, String malade_pat, String medicament_pat, Date der_soin_pat, String mot_de_passe_pat) {
    this.id_pat = id_pat;
    this.cin_pat = cin_pat;
    this.fname_pat = fname_pat;
    this.lname_pat = lname_pat;
    this.sexe_pat = sexe_pat;
    this.date_naissance_pat = date_naissance_pat;
    this.ville_pat = ville_pat;
    this.poid_pat = poid_pat;
    this.mail_pat = mail_pat;
    this.num_tel_pat = num_tel_pat;   
    this.adress_pat = adress_pat;
    this.remarque_pat = remarque_pat;
    this.malade_pat = malade_pat;
    this.medicament_pat = medicament_pat;
    this.der_soin_pat = der_soin_pat;
    this.mot_de_passe_pat = mot_de_passe_pat;
  }

  // Getters & Setters

}
```

patient controller

```
 @RestController
 public class PatientController {

   @Autowired
   PatientService patientService;

   @GetMapping("/patients")
   private List<Patient> getAllPatients() {
     return patientService.getAllPatients();
   }

   @GetMapping("/patients/{id_pat}")
   private Patient getPatient(@PathVariable("id_pat") Integer id_pat){
     return patientService.getPatientById(id_pat) ;
   } 

   @PostMapping("/patients")
   public void addPatient(@RequestBody Patient patient){
     patientService.addPatient(patient);   
   }

   @PutMapping("/patients/{id_pat}")
   public void upatePatient (@RequestBody Patient patient, @PathVariable String id_pat){
     patientService.updatePatient(id_pat, patient);
   }

   @DeleteMapping("/patients/{id_pat}")
   private void deletePatient(@PathVariable("id_pat") Integer id_pat){
     patientService.delete(id_pat);
   }
}
```

patient sevice

```
@Service
public class PatientService {

  @Autowired
  private PatientRepository patientRepository;

  public List<Patient> getAllPatients() {
    List<Patient> patients = new ArrayList<Patient>();
    patientRepository.findAll().forEach(patient-> patients.add(patient));
    return patients;
  }

  public Patient getPatientById(Integer id_pat){
    return patientRepository.findById(id_pat).get();
  }

  public void addPatient(Patient patient) {
    patientRepository.save(patient);
  }

  public void updatePatient(String id_pat, Patient patient){
    patientRepository.save(patient);
  } 

  public void delete(Integer id_pat){
    patientRepository.deleteById(id_pat);
  }
}
```

rdv entity

```
@Entity
public class Rdv {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Integer id_rdv;

  @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
  private Date date_rdv;

  private Time time_rdv;

  @JsonBackReference
  @ManyToOne( fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "id")
  private Medecin medecin;

  @JsonBackReference
  @ManyToOne( fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "id_pat")
  private Patient patient;

  public Rdv() {}

  public Rdv(Integer id_rdv, Date date_rdv, Time time_rdv, Integer id,  Integer id_pat) {
    this.id_rdv = id_rdv;
    this.date_rdv = date_rdv;
    this.time_rdv = time_rdv;
    this.medecin = new Medecin(id, "", "", "", null, "", "", "");
    this.patient = new Patient(id_pat, null, "", "", "", null, "", null, "", null, "", "", "", "", null, "");
  }

  // Getters & Setters

}
```

patient repository

```
  public interface PatientRepository extends JpaRepository<Patient, Integer> {

  }
```

rdv repository

```
 public interface SecretaireRepository extends JpaRepository<Secretaire, Integer>{

   public List<Secretaire> findByMedecinId(Integer id);

 }
```

Comment: First. JsonBackReference only works when used in conjunction with @JsonManagedReference on the other site. Second. I am wondering why your pat_id is an integer in the GetRequest and a String in the PutRequest. Third If you are OR-Mapping. Didn't you need the table and column definition?

Comment: i m working on h2 database

Comment: Did you try adding `consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE` to your post and put methods?

Comment: It is bad practice to have an entity at the controller level. I suggest creating that DTO for that. In addition, when you call you POST API you should have Content-Type: application/json & Accept: application/json